# MinGW-w64 OpenGL linker error

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, linker

I am trying to use OpenGL in a small program I am about to write (in C++). I am using **MinGW-w64** as comiler and I am compiling for Windows. My problem is that all gl-functions seem to produce linker errors, for example: 
`undefined reference to '__imp_wglCreateContext'` or 
`undefined reference to '__imp_wglMakeCurrent'`

Now I'm not sure if I have to link against any OpenGL libraries explicitly (I haven't done so yet). What makes me uncertain about it is that the OpenGL header files are already provided by MinGW-w64.

So my questions is:
Do I explicitly have to link against a OpenGL library, and if so, which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to link against the OpenGL library.  Last time I did it was called "opengl32" but I suspect it might not be called that in this case.  (I seem to recall also having to link against "gdi32", but that may have been for something else.)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Although it was quite evident if I think about it again I just did't get it :)